# Can you choose a git rebase strategy on a commit-by-commit basis?

Tags: git

I was recently faced with the following situation.

We have a master branch `M`, and I was working from a feature branch `F`. Someone rebased `M` and pushed to the remote, and I had to rebase `F` to match it.

There are some conflicts that were already resolved on development, and I know in advance that I want to resolve those in favour of HEAD (i.e. `git rebase -Xours`). But there may be additional conflicts between the new head of `M` and the feature commits that sit on top. I don't know which way I want to resolve those, and I'd like to inspect them.

This made me wonder whether, doing an interactive rebase, there is a way to decide on a strategy for a specific set of conflicts. Something like

```
git rebase --continue -Xours
```

which would resolve this set of conflicts and skip me ahead in the history. I can't see any way to do this (I tried the command above and it didn't work).

Comment: If you create a commit after fixing the merge issue wouldn't you be able to re-run rebase from that new commit?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean. Once the history of master is correct, I need to rebase the feature branch. This will involve re-resolving the master commits (since the feature branch was previously ahead of master), plus fixing any new conflicts which arise.

Hopefully, though, the details of the situation are not super important. I just want to advance a specific stage in the rebase with one strategy.

Comment: On re-reading, I think this question is probably meaningless, and I must have been confused when I wrote it. Once `M` is rebased, the conflicts that arose when rebasing it have already been fixed. If there are conflicts that arise when rebasing onto the new branch, they should not resemble the conflicts that were already resolved. So without an example it's hard even for me to tell what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to re-run current rebase step (pick), i.e. when conflict has been encountered:

1. Discard any changes or conflict state

```
git reset --hard
```

or

```
git checkout -f
```

The former command has a drawback. It changes ORIG_HEAD. Whereas latter does not.

2. Re-run the last step with arbitrary strategy:

```
git cherry-pick -n -s... -X... REBASE_HEAD
```